# Boot Loop Not solved

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, boot-loop, fastboot, troubleshooting

I have a yu yureka AO5510 runs on Cyanogenmod 12.1. I used it without any problem till today morning. But suddenly it started to restarts again and again. If i connect it to the charger, the booting get completed but when it finish boot, again restarts. If I didn't connect charger, even booting is not started. The brand name is shown, again restart likewise. 
**I didn't perform any update, didn't rooted  didn't installed any apps and didn't do anything.** I can access to the recovery menu. I wiped the cache but no use. I connected it to pc in fastboot mode but not detecting. All of my important data are stored in it and so I can't erase it simply.

**Things I have done so far**

- Remove battery and inserted again
- Recovery mode -> wiped cache
- Connected to laptop in fastboot but not detecting.

I checked the recovery logs and it contains something like

```
missing clock cycle property
IRQ32 no longer affine to CPU4
Started secondary processor
```

**Suggestions I want**

- How to interact it to fastboot or adb
- How to copy data from that device to laptop
- How to solve the booy loop issue

Comment: You need fastboot drivers to get the phone be detected by the computer. Flashing the phone should solve the issue. Flash only the system partition (With SP Flashtool)

Comment: yes. I saw a video on youtube and updated the drivers. No it is detected on fastboot but not on adb. I want to copy the data

Comment: The phone must be on and USB Debugging enabled to be detected with ADB. While not booted in android, the phone can only be accessed in falsh mode and fastboot mode/ meta mode.

Comment: is there any alternative method for `adb pull` in fastboot mode

Comment: Nope! Fastboot has limited functionalities

Comment: There are tools that can dump all phone data, but most are paid.